# Print numbers in specific range using loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

How to print the following sequence using a simple loop in Java

```
10, 11, 11, 12,12,12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14
```

Comment: Need more details also or I can answer that `for(;;){System.out.println("10, 11, 11, 12,12,12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14");break;}` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int currentNumber = 10;
int timesToPrint = 1;
int timesPrinted = 0;

while(currentNumber < 15){

System.out.println(currentNumber);
timesPrinted++;

if(timesPrinted == timesToPrint){
     timesToPrint++;
     timesPrinted = 0;
     currentNumber++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
int num=10;
for(int i=1 ;i<10;i++)
  {
   for(int j=0;j<i;j++) 
     { 
      System.out.print(num+",");
     }
   num ++;
  }
```

Comment: Since the OP is having an issue understanding how this is done, it may be good to change the variable names to be more meaningful

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't want to do your homework for you, but notice the pattern here. There is 1 10, 2 11s, 3 12s etc....

you need a loop that starts at 10 and ends at 14 which looks like:

```
for(int i = 10; i<=14; i++){
  //print i
}
```

but instead of just printing i once, you need to print it 1,2,3,4, or 5 times.
One way to do this is to create another variable that starts at 1 and increases every time i increases. Then create another loop nested in the first that prints i that many times. That should be enough to get you started. Feel free to ask questions if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "";
     int timer = 1;
        for (int i =10; i<15; i++) 
        {
            for (int a = 0; a<timer; a++)
            {
                s += i + ", ";
            }
           timer++;
        }
        System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent really shown that you have done any work yourself... Anyway

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    for(int ii = 0; ii <=i; ii++){
        int numbertoshow = 10+i;
        System.out.print(numbertoshow+", ");
    }
}
```

Output:

10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14,

The first loop specifies what the end digit will be (e.g if i = 0, 10+i = 10, so the output will be 10).
The second loop will make it repeat the output (i) times, (e.g, if i = 2, 10+i = 12, so it will output 12 when ii is equal to 0, 1 and 2, hence 3 times)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a counter in order to know "How many numbers, did you printed so far".
Let me name it `counter`. You have to Declare it as an `integer`

By now, we can see that your string of numbers, has a special order, it seems like: `counter%10 + 10` (where `%` sign is represented `Modulo` calculation).

So by now you can do the following:

```
public class Printer { // Create a class which its responsibility is to print requested string
    public static void main(String[] args) { // The entry point of almost every java program
        int end = 4; // As you want to print until 14
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= end; ++counter) { // A for loop counts steps so far
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i) { // Here we print the number as many as counter
                System.out.print(10 + counter%10 + ","); // System.out.print is a bulit in function which prints the given string
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Now you can change the value of `end` in third line, in order to get more numbers as well